# My favorite holiday destination

Tags: cipher, rebus

My favorite holiday destination is hidden in this secret message. Can you find what it is?

[image]

Hint 1:

> The chosen colors are not important and the puzzle can be solved without them. They do provide some hints though.

Hint 2:

> The destination is a real geographical location in my country.

Hint 3:

> Each row of the grid can be decoded into a single English letter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your favourite destination is:

> [**Gold Coast**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_Coast,_Queensland), Queensland

Each of the rows ...

> ... is a two-digit number encoded in Morse code. The numbers in Morse are five signals each with a regular pattern:
>
>        `0 -----    1 ·----   2 ··---   3 ···--   4 ····-`
>        `5 ·····    6 -····   7 --···   8 ---··   9 ----·`
>
>  This patters , where there is at most on change between the symbols, is visible in the code. The "rift" in the middle denotes the boundary between the digits.
>
>  Treating coloured squares as dashes and white squares as dots, we get seven numbers between 1 and 21, which we can treat as indoces of letters in the alphabet (A is 1, Z is 26):
>
>        `----- .----   01   A`
>        `..--- .----   21   U`
>        `----- ...--   03   C`
>        `.---- .....   15   O`
>        `----- .----   01   A`
>        `.---- ----.   19   S`
>        `..--- -----   20   T`
>
>  Au is the chemical symbol of gold. It's also the two-letter code for Australia, which is nice. The colours in the image indicate the two words. They represent the blue ocean and the "gold coast".
>
>  Have a nice holiday! `:)`

Comment: Bingo! Correct and well done. You even explained the colours. I was worried that no one will get this one and I would have to spell it out :)